# How to make sure that no threads are created without a custom name?

Tags: java, multithreading

There are multiple people working on project and I want to make sure that everyone gives logical name to their thread so that its easy to debug and read logs.

I tried following, but it fails due to a very fundamental reason which I realized later. I am putting this code here so that It make my purpose more clear to all of you.

```
public abstract class MyRunnableAbstract implements Runnable 
{ 
    public MyRunnableAbstract (String pThreadName)
    {
        Thread.currentThread().setName(pThreadName);

    }
}
```

Here, everyone who wants to create a thread must extend this class and not implement Runnable directly. This way, you have to pass name to super constructor without fail.

Above doesn't work because constructor is executed as part of parent thread, hence `currentThread()` sets name of parent thread and not the one which is being created.

But I want to do something similar, where no one will be able to create thread without passing a name.

Is there a way ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What makes you think developers will respect the rule to extend that class instead of implementing Runnable? This is as easily violated as forgetting to give a name to create a thread. Quite frankly, a good app should very very rarely create threads. Most of the time, using a higher-level abstraction (an ExecutorService) is the right solution.

Comment: There is a way, it's called "code review."–Nobody checks any change in to the source code repository until the change as been reviewed by another team member.  And, if anybody refuses to play by the rules, you kick them off the team.

Answer (score 3):

Since you want to change the behavior of Thread, the obvious thing to do is to extend Thread. The extension class should expose only constructors that take a name parameter.

Of course, you also need a programming convention that prohibits the direct use of Thread.

Comment: One of the very few reasons to actually extend Thread! Although using threads directly is still in almost all situations wrong, so..

Comment: Better still:  If you are going to extend Thread, then you probably should be passing around a ThreadFactory.  (See @hagrawal 's response, below).

Answer (score 2):

[ThreadFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadFactory.html) is your friend, my friend. It is meant for that purpose - a central location to create all custom threads of your application; an example of factory design pattern. See below code:

```
public class SimpleThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {
    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        return new Thread(r);
    }

    public Thread createCustomThreadWithName(Runnable r, String threadName) throws Exception {
        if(threadName == null || threadName.isEmpty()){
            throw new Exception("Please provide a thread name");
        }
        Thread thread = newThread(r);
        thread.setName(threadName);
        return thread;
    }

}
```

Comment: Did some answer helped ??

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to block users to program badly. You can extends `Thread` for example as follow:

```
public class NamedThread extends Thread {
    public NamedThread(String name) {
        super();
        setName(name);
    }
}
```

Then you have to inform you working team that people who is not using the new `NamedThread` is sanctioned... for example... they must offer a Pizza to the whole group each time they use a normal `Thread` instead of `NamedThread` :-D

If after a month the whole group has gained 10 kilos... probably your group is not working following your directions :-D